# How can I protect an endpoint so that the same user cannot call it more than once?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, nestjs

I have an endpoint which creates a document on a NestJS server.
But if a user call it multiple time at the same time, multiple documents will be created.
But I have a limit, every user can create only 2 documents.
The limit checking does not work if the server gets two requests to the same endpoint at the same time, because it checks the documents number in the database and if it is >=2, it throws an error. But this check run at the ~same time and the script can see only one document in the database and the server creates 2 documents if the user tries to make multiple requests at the same time somehow.
What is the best way in NestJS to handle this situation?
I don't want to allow to create more than 2 documents and handle the multiple requests at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Create a data structure or an in-memory map in your nest-application to keep track of user IDs that have already initiated the document creation process.

Before creating a document, check if the user ID already exists in the data structure or map. If it does, you can cancel the request or return an appropriate error response indicating that a document creation is already in progress for that user ID.

Once you start the document creation, add the user ID to the data structure or map to indicate that the process is in progress.

Important: This solution assumes that your server application runs in a single instance! If you have multiple instances (e.g. in a serverless environment), the two requests could hit separate instances.

In that case you could store the information in the database instead of holding it in-memory!